# TextBox to accept enter/return

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the below code that allows a user to write in a executable (i.e. *notepad.exe*) and then clicking the start button it will start the process.

However, how do I make the `TextBox` accept enter/return key? I put in `AcceptsReturn=true` but it is not doing anything. I have also set in Visual Studio the property `Accept Return = True` - still nothing.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace process_list
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = textBox1.Text;
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = text;
            process.Start();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) of the form to your button. You don't need `AcceptsReturn` then, because <kbd>Enter</kbd> automatically triggers the button.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AcceptButton = button1;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Add `KeyDown` event method to `textBox1` and inside the method do this

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        button1_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: +1 This would most definitely help if you have multiple text boxes in a form and have a default button corresponding to each text box. For e.g. a search box and a button.